# How to upload a video to server using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Now using below code for uploading data. But I need to upload binary data with mp4 format. now I get only file path that is allow move format but I need to convert mp4 for that path.

```
UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

 imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];



-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{

    NSString *videoPath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

}
```

Comment: For uploading video to server you need to use NSUrlSession

Answer (score 1):

You can upload file in bytes format using `NSUrlSession`. Convert the file into `NSData` and attach it to your request. In your imagePicker delegate, you can do it like this:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
    NSString *videoPath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoPath];

    NSURLRequest *uploadRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your server url"]];
    [uploadRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] uploadTaskWithRequest: uploadRequest fromData: videoData completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        //Handle your response here
    });

    [uploadTask resume];
}
```

Comment: kindly go through this -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245929/uploading-video-file-to-server-from-iphone

Comment: NSURLConnection is now deprecated. From now use NSURLSession instead of NSURLConnection.